# Google Maps Geolocation API implementation through Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-maps, geolocation

I have been trying to use the new Geolocation API. I got an API key too.
But somehow, the output is given as 'Not found'.
Can someone please tell me where the error is?

> ```
> require 'net/http'
> require 'uri'
> require 'json'
> require 'httparty'
>
>
> lac=50039
> mnc=86
> cid=15471
> mcc=404
> rssi=-69
>
>
>     cell_towers = [{:cellId => cid,
>   :locationAreaCode => lac,
>   :mobileCountryCode => mcc,
>   :mobileNetworkCode => mnc,
>   :signalStrength => rssi }] 
>
>     param = {:cellTowers => cell_towers}
>    puts param.to_json
>    #puts "https://www.googleapis.com/maps/api/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=#{api_key}"
>
>       response = HTTParty.post("https://www.googleapis.com/maps/api/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=my_key",
>       :body => param.to_json, 
>       :header => {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})
>       puts response
>       temp= response.body
>       puts temp
> ```

The output the above code gives is :

> {"cellTowers":[{"cellId":15471,"locationAreaCode":50039,"mobileCountryCode":404,"mobileNetworkCode":86,"signalStrength":-69}]}
>   Not Found
>   Not Found

The link to the documentation of Google Maps Geolocation API : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

When I create a json object manually and run it on command prompt using 'curl' command, the output is coming out right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was struggling with this exact same issue, but using a simple http post in .Net...

Seems the API documentation concerning the URL is wrong.

Instead of: https://www.googleapis.com/maps/api/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_key

It's actually: https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_key

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!I have changed the URL. The 'Not found' error is no longer being showed.
But I'm getting an error with code 403,saying "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." Not able to figure out why. The authentication has been done, I got an API key and I have checked the API console too. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a credit card on file via your API console? Since this is a business API, I do believe it's required. After that you should be able to use your allotted 100 requests-per-day.

Comment: Issue got solved, I had to set verify_none for SSL certification. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

With all your help, I could solve the issue.Thanks!
Thought I'll share the code.It might be helpful.

```
cell_towers = [{:cellId => cid,
                :locationAreaCode => lac,
                :mobileCountryCode => mcc,
                :mobileNetworkCode => mnc,
                :signalStrength => rssi }] 

param = {:cellTowers => cell_towers}
uri = URI.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=your_key')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body=param.to_json
request["Content-Type"]="application/json"
response = http.request(request)
result=response.body
res=JSON.parse(result)
lat=res["location"]["lat"]
long=res["location"]["lng"]
```